# What does "_sre.SRE_Match" refers to in match.group()

Tags: python

I am following an instruction to learn regex:

```
In [269]: phone_number_regex
Out[269]: re.compile(r'\d\d\d-\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d', re.UNICODE)
In [270]: mo = phone_number_regex.search("My number is 415-555-4242")
In [273]: mo.group()
Out[273]: '415-555-4242'
In [274]: help(mo.group)
```

> group(...) method of _sre.SRE_Match instance
>       group([group1, ...]) -> str or tuple.
>       Return subgroup(s) of the match by indices or names.
>       For 0 returns the entire match.

What does `sre.SRE` refers to here?

It's not a bulitin methods:

```
In [285]: [ elem for elem in dir(mo.group) if "_sre" in elem]
Out[285]: []
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `re` lib is actually mostly a C extension package  with a python wrapper over it. `_sre` is the C extention module and `_sre.SRE_Match` is the (C-coded) `Match` class. You'll find it in `sys.modules`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import re
>>> sys.modules["_sre"]
<<module '_sre' (built-in)>
```